Ng build fails for SSR with new esbuild application builder Angular v17
I'm trying to implement server side rendering on my project with angular version 17 and it has new esbuild application builder. I'm getting following error while ng build.
An unhandled exception occurred: The service was stopped
Content from angular-errors.log file :
[error] Error: The service was stopped at D:..path\main.js:1111:28 at responseCallbacks. (D:..path\main.js:704:9) at Socket.afterClose (D:\path..\main.js:694:28) at Socket.emit (node:events:524:35) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12) at process.process TicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
I've updated my node version from 19 to 20.16.0 thinking it would solve the issue but it didn't.I tried standard build prior to adding @angular/ssr. For standard build, it was failing one time and next time it will build the application successfully. But for SSR it's failing everytime.
